# Vite use bad path for css file imported in stylus file

Tags: vite, stylus

I'm using vite with stylus. The files are :

```
/src/
  stylesheet/
    project.styl
    one.styl
    two.css
  main.js
```

**main.js**

```js
import './stylesheet/project.styl'
```

**project.styl**

```
@require 'one'
@require 'two.css'
```

**vite.config.js**

```js
...
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        port: 8080,
        strictPort: true
    },
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                includePaths: ['node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'],
            },
        },
    },
})
```

Using vite dev server, `two.css` isn't loaded by because the vite browser client try to fetch the file : `/two.css` (at root path).
Stylus compiler does not complain about a bad path.

What can I do t have vite either handle the css file path or let stylus include the file in it compilation process (as expected) ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I'm having the same trouble but with SCSS and vite+rollup

Comment: No, i'm importing others (s)css file from main.js
`import './stylesheet/vendors.scss';
import './stylesheet/project.styl';`